# I asked for too much money in salary negotiations. Should I call them with a revised figure?

Tags: salary, negotiation

I had a successful interview and when asked what salary I expected I believe I have asked for too much. I've been living in New York City which is why I based my salary where I did but I believe that this area commands a higher salary then where my new position would be.

Should I contact them and mention that I am willing to negotiate the figure?

Comment: I suspect they're used to this...

Comment: To be clear, the last two sentences of your question say identical things.

Comment: BAD IDEA! Don't say anything. If they really like you they will make you a counter-offer. If it's lower you can ask for more perks like an extra few days of vacation instead of the money - don't just give in and act like losing out on the money doesn't bother you at all. The ball is in their court, way and see how it plays out.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I felt bad I quoted a higher salary as its a NGO. But I will keep quiet and let them come back to me with a counter offer.

Comment: What if they accept?

Comment: Keep in mind that well-run NGOs are used to paying competitive salaries. If you feel compelled to support their mission you can just donate money or do volunteer work *that's unrelated to your paid position*. "Donating" by accepting a lower salary is likely to just lead to unhappiness in your job.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. If they want you they will make you an offer - this may not be what you expected (or suggested) but you can guarantee they will have looked at the relevant salaries for the area and work and will offer you something in that region - and probably bumped up a little too.

Leave that decision on how much to offer to them. Never go back and start sounding desperate for the job by making offers to them, it never looks good.

now, if they reject you, it is reasonable to mention to your agent about the NYC salary, and that if that was the problem you would be willing to accept less in order to "join such a great team" or similar, and let the agent handle that on your behalf. Chances are though, salary expectations are never the issue for a candidate they want - if they cannot pay enough, they will come back and suggest a salary to put the ball back in your court to reject (or not).

Answer (score 4):

## Wait for more information...

If you think there's any damage being done by this, its already happened. They're unlikely to not get back to you with anything and even if they can't match the offer you made then they will get back to you with *something*. See what they come back with, then decide how you want to move from there.

## Consider if you really do want less

You clearly said this figure for a reason. Are you rethinking it now because you're nervous and sick of waiting to hear back from them? Make sure before taking anything less you've completely considered whether you can afford it. You don't want to accept a lower offer now just to become bitter later because of it. Ultimately if they can't meet this figure maybe the job isn't for you.